# The 'active' class is not showing on the 'li' image. It just gets removed but it does not move onto the next image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the source code for the javascript and the source code of the page.  Any help would be really appreciated as I am losing my mind.

The 'active' class is not showing on the 'li' image. It just gets removed but it does not move onto the next image.

The link to the website is https://doozydog.co.uk/dev/satelliet-uk/product/wrap-steel-lounge-armchair/

```js
"use strict";

jQuery(window).load(function () {

   

    //jCarousel Plugin
    jQuery('#tzShopDetail_carousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 2,
        navigation: false,
        wrap: 'last',
        //itemLoadCallback: {
        //    onBeforeAnimation: function(){
        //        interiart_resize_image(jQuery('#tzShopDetail_slide ul li'));
        //    }
        //},
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });

    jQuery("#tzShopDetailSlide-carousel ul li a").each(function(){
        interiart_resize_image(jQuery(this));
    });

    //Front page Carousel - Initial Setup

    jQuery('div#tzShopDetail_slide li:first').addClass('active');
    //jQuery('div#tzShopDetailSlide-carousel a img').css({'opacity': '0.5'});
    jQuery('div#tzShopDetailSlide-carousel ul li:first').addClass('bd_active');
//    jQuery('div#slideshow-carousel li a:first').append('<span class="arrow"></span>')

    //Combine jCarousel with Image Display
    jQuery('div#tzShopDetailSlide-carousel li a').on('click',function () {

            jQuery('span.arrow').remove();
//            jQuery(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
            jQuery('div#tzShopDetailSlide-carousel ul li.bd_active').removeClass('bd_active');
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('bd_active');
            jQuery('div#tzShopDetail_slide li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('div#tzShopDetail_slide li.' + jQuery(this).attr('data-link')).addClass('active');

            return false;
        });

    interiart_resize_image(jQuery('#tzShopDetail_slide ul li '));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have class names with a `.` in them

So, jQuery gets confused, because `div#tzShopDetail_slide li.Wrap-Steel-Lounge-Armchair.jpg` is looking for an element with `class=Wrap-Steel-Lounge-Armchair jpg` - note the SPACE instead of the `.`

Personally, I would avoid classnames with `.` or `#` or `>` - i.e. anything that has a particular meaning in CSS selectors

However, in your case, you can fix the problem by *escaping* the `.` in the selector

```
jQuery('div#tzShopDetail_slide li.' + jQuery(this).attr('data-link').replace('.', '\\.')).addClass('active');
```

Or, if there could be MORE than one `.` in the class name

```
jQuery('div#tzShopDetail_slide li.' + jQuery(this).attr('data-link').replace(/\./g, '\\.')).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for this information, I completely overlooked this as being an issue.  Works perfectly!